# What does the crosshatching mean on this VOR-DME?

Tags: navaids

I noticed that the frequency of this VOR-DME is covered by crosshatching. 
[image: detail of sectional]

The FAA chart guide says this "indicates shutdown status." 
[image: chart guide detail]

What does this mean? Is this navaid being decommissioned?

Comment: Think I answered my own question. Looks like the VOR is gone but the DME is still operational.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right. From *FAA Aeronautical Chart User’s Guide*,

> NAVAIDS in a shutdown status have the frequency and channel number  crosshatched. Use of the NAVAID status “shutdown” is only used when a facility has been decommissioned but cannot be published as such because of pending airspace actions.

[image: Shutdown Status]

Image from *FAA Aeronautical Chart User’s Guide*, 12th Ed.

FAA is in the process of reducing the VOR based navigation network to minimum levels so as to provide only an alternate means of navigation in case of Global Navigation Satellite System (GNSS) outage. This VOR Minimum Operational Network (MON) is expected to be in place by the year 2020, which will permit non-GNSS guidance to an airport within 100 nautical miles (nm) that has an ILS or VOR approach procedure.

Comment: Why would "pending airspace actions" render the FAA unable to officially publish the VOR as being decommissioned?