# Why would a VOR be decommissioned leaving the DME?

Tags: vor, navaids

As can be seen on [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/24040/8730) and [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/22128/8730) the OJC VOR has been decommissioned but the DME is still active. What would be the purpose in having DME without VOR?

Comment: OCJ is directly short of a runway, so the DME could still be useful in combination with the ILS.

Comment: With 3 distances from a DME you can know exactly where you are on a 2D map (in contrast with only 2 from a VOR and 1 from a VOR+DME)

Comment: FMS can use DME DME for position update as DME is more accurate. VOR is not used

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Many older Air Transport Airplanes have no GPS. I'm a pilot since 1970. I operated A330 for 5 years until 2000 without GPS. The average IRS position (Inertial Reference Systems) in the FMS was updated by DME/DME. On older airplanes we selected the DME Stations manually preferably with a 90 degree cut-angle to obtain an accurate update. A single VOR/DME station could be used for update as well but it's a lot less accurate. Example, if you are 60 NM away from a VOR, a 1° error in azimuth would cause an error of about 1 NM. All Airbus aircraft have an approval for RNAV Approaches down to an accuracy of 0,3 NM with 2 DME stations available. This is why DME's are still useful, many ILS have a DME. Conventional VORs are terribly inaccurate, Doppler VORs are much better even down to a lower altitude, but requires more space.

Comment: I never realized dme had so many uses as a standalone device. And welcome to aviation.se. We get a lot of airbus questions here and i don't *think* anybody else on here has flown them. It'll be nice to have your pov.